# SQL Multiple Sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to find all the entries with the same IDs in two sub queries and display the first table. I am having an issue with using aliases.

```
(SELECT *
 FROM personTable
 WHERE ID IN
     (     SELECT ID
           FROM workerTable
     ) 
 AND firstName LIKE 'O%');


 (SELECT *
  FROM ownsTable
  WHERE PhoneNumberID IN
      ( SELECT ID
        FROM phonenumberTable
        WHERE Home <>'' AND `Work` <>'' AND Cell <>''
      )
  );
```

I want to now check the first table's 'ID' against the second table's 'PersonID' and return the rows in the first table where ID and PersonID match.

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Please show your table schema, some sample data from tables and a clear explanation of the desired end result, such that you can hopefully get better advice on how to leverage joins to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Exists` to do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   persontable p 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   workertable) 
       AND firstname LIKE 'O%' 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   ownstable o 
                   WHERE  phonenumberid IN (SELECT id 
                                            FROM   phonenumbertable 
                                            WHERE  home <> '' 
                                                   AND ` work ` <> '' 
                                                   AND cell <> '') 
                          AND p.id = o.personid);
```

Also if possible convert the `IN` to `Exists` in all the `sub-queries` might be little efficient

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I kept trying to use 'AS' but my syntax was incorrect so  AND p.id = o.personid); worked great.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just do a simple join for this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM personTable p
JOIN ownsTable o ON o.id = p.id AND p.firstName LIKE 'O%' AND o.home <> '' AND o.work <> '' AND o.cell <> '';
```

This will select all columns from the first table as long as the id exists in the second table, and the matching rows meet the given requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you :)

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM personTable
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM workerTable) 
      AND firstName LIKE 'O%')T1 
    JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM ownsTable
    WHERE PhoneNumberID IN
      ( SELECT ID FROM phonenumberTable WHERE Home <>'' AND `Work` <>'' AND Cell <>'')) T2 
   ON (T1.ID = T2.PersonId);
```